# How can I delete a list item in SwiftUI from a child view without using onDelete(perform:)?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a chat feature in my app that allows you to report and block someone from communicating with you any further.

Here's my `InboxView.swift` that shows a user's conversations:

```
List(Array(conversations.conversations.enumerated()), id: \.1.id){ (index, conversation) in
    VStack{
        NavigationLink(destination: ChatView(conversation_id: conversation.id, avatar: conversation.avatar, displayName: conversation.displayName, user_id: conversation.receiver_id, parentIndex: index)){
        ConversationList(id : conversation.id, user_id : conversation.user_id, receiver_id : conversation.receiver_id, lastMessage : conversation.lastMessage, avatar : conversation.avatar, displayName : conversation.displayName, startedAt : conversation.startedAt)
        }
        Divider()
    }
}
```

The above code simply provides the end-user an interface for them to select which conversation they want to go into. Here's where things get tricky with the following view diagram:

`InboxView --> ChatView --> ProfileView`

Each `-->` represents a `NavigationLink` that leads to the subsequent view. On the `ProfileView.Swift` page, I present a button in which the end-user can block the person they are talking to. I have already figured out how to take the user back to `InboxView` with a series of

`@Environment(\.presentationMode) var mode`

and

`self.mode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`

but for convenience, I also want to delete the list item that was associated with the blocked user's conversation.

How can I tell `InboxView` which `ChatView` triggered the delete request and pass that through a function like this?

```
func removeRow(at offsets: IndexSet){
    if let first = offsets.first {
        let conversationRemoving = conversations.conversations[first]
        conversations.conversations.remove(at:first)
    }
}
```

I don't see in the documentation for `presentationMode` to trigger a function via `wrappedValue`

Comment: Well, I feel silly. I was overthinking this one. I just added an onAppear() to my List and asked my API for the new list of conversations. However, it would be neat if someone could drop an answer to reduce the need to make another API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done directly inside `List` (as we have access to index in it) and remove record from already fetched results.

If person model would have specific field (say `blocked`), then it could be like below (in pseudo-code, to be shorter):

```
List(Array(conversations.conversations.enumerated()), id: \.1.id){ (index, conversation) in
    VStack{
        NavigationLink(destination: ChatView(...)) {
            ConversationList(...)
        }
        Divider()
    }
    .onAppear { // called on show and on return back
        if conversation.receiver.blocked {         // << here !!
           // better to do it asynchronously
           DispatchQueue.main.async {     
              self.conversations.conversations.remove(at: index)    // << here !!
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is clever. I had not considered modifying the Conversation model to include a Bool for blocked. I have that info saved in a separate table, but I guess I can also place it here. I'll experiment with this tonight and let you know how it goes. Thanks!